# SQL(POSTGRESQL) how to return sum = 0 when use group by by no data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.payment_type, 
CASE WHEN SUM(fee_total) > 0 THEN SUM(fee_total) ELSE 0 END
FROM tbl_order AS o
WHERE payment_type IS NOT NULL
AND created_at BETWEEN '2022-09-25' AND '2022-09-25'
GROUP BY o.payment_type
```

this is the data

"CARD"  47723090 
"CASH"  953411890 
"TRANSFER"  55470090 
"WALLET"    14200000

solution: no data sum return 0, help me, please!!!!!!

Comment: Not clear the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use count() function to help

example:
tabl.id <>1

```sql
select sum(id) from tab1 where id = 1 limit 10;--null
select case when count(1)>0 then sum(id) else 0 end as sm from tab1 where id = 1 limit 10;--0
select case when count(1)>0 then sum(id) else 0 end as sm from tab1 where id = 2 limit 10;--2
```